# getting transformer results from sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am using a `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` object for my clustering.

```
pipe = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([('transformer1': transformer1),
                                  ('transformer2': transformer2),
                                  ('clusterer': clusterer)])
```

Then I am evaluating the result by using the silhouette score.

```
sil = preprocessing.silhouette_score(X, y)
```

I'm wondering how I can get the `X` or the transformed data from the pipeline as it only returns the `clusterer.fit_predict(X)`.

I understand that I can do this by just splitting the pipeline as

```
pipe = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([('transformer1': transformer1),
                                  ('transformer2': transformer2)])

X = pipe.fit_transform(data)
res = clusterer.fit_predict(X)
sil = preprocessing.silhouette_score(X, res)
```

but I would like to just do it all in one pipeline.

Comment: to be clear, im interested in getting out intermediate results such as `transformer1.fit_transform(df)` and `transformer2.fit_transform(transformer1.fit_transform(df))`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to both fit and transform the data on intermediate steps of the pipeline then it makes no sense to reuse the same pipeline and better to use a new one as you specified, because calling `fit()` will forget all about previously learnt data.

However if you only want to `transform()` and see the intermediate data on an already fitted pipeline, then its possible by accessing the [`named_steps`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) parameter.

```
new_pipe = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([('transformer1': 
                                           old_pipe.named_steps['transformer1']),
                                      ('transformer2': 
                                          old_pipe.named_steps['transformer2'])])
```

Or directly using the inner varible `steps` like:

```
transformer_steps = old_pipe.steps
new_pipe = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([('transformer1': transformer_steps[0]),
                                  ('transformer2': transformer_steps[1])])
```

And then calling the `new_pipe.transform()`.

**Update:** 
If you have version 0.18 or above, then you can set the non-required estimator inside the pipeline to `None` to get the result in same pipeline. Its discussed in [this issue at scikit-learn github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7536)
Usage for above in your case:

```
pipe.set_params(clusterer=None)
pipe.transform(df)
```

But be aware to maybe store the fitted `clusterer` somewhere else to do so, else you need to fit the whole pipeline again when wanting to use that functionality.