# Get intermediate data state in scikit-learn Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Given the  following example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd

pipe = Pipeline([
    ("tf_idf", TfidfVectorizer()),
    ("nmf", NMF())
])

data = pd.DataFrame([["Salut comment tu vas", "Hey how are you today", "I am okay and you ?"]]).T
data.columns = ["test"]

pipe.fit_transform(data.test)
```

I would like to get intermediate data state in scikit learn pipeline corresponding to tf_idf output (after fit_transform on tf_idf but not NMF) or NMF input.
Or to say things in another way, it would be the same than to apply

```
TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(data.test)
```

I know pipe.named_steps["tf_idf"] ti get intermediate transformer, but I can't get data, only parameters of the transformer with this method.

Comment: If you want to just view the data each time you fit the pipeline, you can add a new custom transformer in the pipeline which prints the data sent to its `fit()`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As @Vivek Kumar suggested in the comment and as I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802465/sklearn-is-there-any-way-to-debug-pipelines/46591092#46591092), I find a debug step that prints information or writes intermediate dataframes to csv useful:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator


class Debug(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def transform(self, X):
        print(X.shape)
        self.shape = shape
        # what other output you want
        return X

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

pipe = Pipeline([
    ("tf_idf", TfidfVectorizer()),
    ("debug", Debug()),
    ("nmf", NMF())
])

data = pd.DataFrame([["Salut comment tu vas", "Hey how are you today", "I am okay and you ?"]]).T
data.columns = ["test"]

pipe.fit_transform(data.test)
```

### Edit

I now added a state to the debug transformer. Now you can access the shape as in the answer by @datasailor with:

```
pipe.named_steps["debug"].shape
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about adding this steps, but it's not really what i want. I would prefer to get dataset directly in python, because I want to reuse it for plotting, another model and else. Nevertheless, it's my question that wasn't clear enough and your reply is still usefull.

Comment: See my edit. I combined it with the answer by @datasailor. You can add a state to the debug step (e.g. the features) and access these later as he suggests.

Comment: Why is fit() not doing anything here and just returning self? I want to know shape of X during fitting and transform separately. The current code wont give me shape during pipe.fit(X_train). How would i fix it?

Answer (score 13):

As far as I understand, you want to get the transformed training data. You already fitted the data in `pipe.named_steps["tf_idf"]`, so just use this fitted model to transform the training data again:

```
pipe.named_steps["tf_idf"].transform(data.test)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used that, but in my case the pipeline is huge, so there is many transformer applied before my tf_idf (the given example is just a reproducible example).

Comment: Maybe this approach helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626780/getting-transformer-results-from-sklearn-pipeline-pipeline

There the idea is to construct a new (shorter) pipeline of parts of the already fitted full pipeline and use the transform method of this new pipeline.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer something more direct, but if nothing exist it could work.

Answer (score 1):

I've create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tommct/ef7309d7162da649849af43f3cc3fe12) for this. Essentially, from Python 3.2, using the [Context Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html), the code below allows for one to retrieve intermediate results into a dict with the names of the pipeline transformers as keys.

```
with intermediate_transforms(pipe):
    Xt = pipe.transform(X)
    intermediate_results = pipe.intermediate_results__
```

This is accomplished via the function below, but see my gist for more documentation.

```
import contextlib
from functools import partial

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

@contextlib.contextmanager
def intermediate_transforms(pipe: Pipeline):
    # Our temporary overload of Pipeline._transform() method.
    # https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/pipeline.py
    def _pipe_transform(self, X):
        Xt = X
        for _, name, transform in self._iter():
            Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
            self.intermediate_results__[name] = Xt
        return Xt

    if not isinstance(pipe, Pipeline):
        raise ValueError(f'"{pipe}" must be a Pipeline.')

    pipe.intermediate_results__ = {}                              
    _transform_before = pipe._transform
    pipe._transform = partial(_pipe_transform, pipe)  # Monkey-patch our _pipe_transform method.
    yield pipe  # Release our patched object to the context
    
    # Restore
    pipe._transform = _transform_before
    delattr(pipe, 'intermediate_results__')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what your use case is, but one simple solution is this:

```
# get feature values by transforming x for each step, except the classifier 

x_intermediate = data.train

for step in pipe.steps[:-1]:
    x_intermediate = step[1].transform(x_intermediate)

print(x_intermediate)
```

Good luck-
Tony

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use:

```py
def fit_transform_step(pipe, X, y=None, step_name=None):
    if step_name not in pipe.named_steps:
        raise ValueError(f"step not in Pipeline: {step_name}")
    Xt = X
    for k,v in pipe.steps:
        if v != 'passthrough':
            Xt = v.fit_transform(Xt, y)
        if k==step_name:
            break
    return Xt
```

call like:

```py
tf_idf_out = fit_transform_step(pipe, data.test, step_name='tf_idf')
```

Answer (score 1):

Slicing a pipeline returns a new pipeline with a subset of the steps.

For example, you can get a sub-pipeline (without the last step) using `pipe[:-1]`

```py
transformed = pipe[:-1].fit_transform(X, y)  # what the final estimator gets
```

If you've already called `fit()` then change `fit_transform` to `transform`.

If you want a Pandas dataframe with column names (and you're transforming columns too), you can do:

```py
sub_pipe = pipe[:-1]
transformed_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=sub_pipe.fit_transform(X, y),
    columns=sub_pipe.get_feature_names_out(),
)
```

If you're calling transform multiple times, you'll probably want to supply the `memory` argument to `Pipeline()` to cache the results. See [Caching transformers: avoid repeated computation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#caching-transformers-avoid-repeated-computation) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Using slicing: `model[:-1].transform(X)` where model is the Pipeline object. Note that you need to call `pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)` on your pipeline object first.