# How to analyse the intermediate steps of sklearn-pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using the sklearn to classify the text into categories. I am using CountVectorizer and TFIDFTransformer to create the sparse matrix.

I am performing couple of pre-processing steps on string in the custom`tokenize_and_stem` function used in CountVectorizer tokenizer.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

SVM = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(max_features=100000,\
                                         ngram_range= (1, 2),stop_words='english',tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem)),\
                         ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf= True)),\
                         ('clf-svm', LinearSVC(C=1)),])
```

my question here is, if there is any easy way available to view/store the output of step 1/2 of Pipeline to analyse what kind of array is going into svm ?

Comment: Please look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743032/get-intermediate-data-state-in-scikit-learn-pipeline?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Using slicing: `model[:-1].transform(X)` where model is the Pipeline object, in your example SVM.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the intermediate steps output with something like this.

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/pipeline.py#L378):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range= (1, 2),stop_words='english')),\
                     ('clf-svm', LinearSVC(C=1)),])
X= ["I want to test this document", "let us see how it works", "I am okay and you ?"]

pipeline.fit(X,[0,1,1])

print(pipeline.named_steps['vect'].get_feature_names())

['document', 'let', 'let works', 'okay', 'test', 'test document', 'want', 'want test', 'works']    

#Here is where you can get the output of intermediate steps
Xt = X

for name, transform in pipeline.steps[:-1]:
    if transform is not None:
        Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
        
print(Xt)



  (0, 7)    0.4472135954999579
  (0, 6)    0.4472135954999579
  (0, 5)    0.4472135954999579
  (0, 4)    0.4472135954999579
  (0, 0)    0.4472135954999579
  (1, 8)    0.5773502691896257
  (1, 2)    0.5773502691896257
  (1, 1)    0.5773502691896257
  (2, 3)    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html):

> named_steps : bunch object, a dictionary with attribute access
>   Read-only attribute to access any step parameter by user given name.
>   Keys are step names and values are steps parameters.

You should be able to access the elements as though it were a dictionary

```
SVM.named_steps['vect']
```

Comment: This is the output i am getting after running the above code, not sure how it will help:
 CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=100000, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 2), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=<function tokenize_and_stem at 0x000000001B9996A8>,
        vocabulary=None)

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood the question. That is the CountVectorizer object stored in the pipeline. You can access any of its attributes as you normally would. e.g., `SVM.named_steps['vect'].vocabulary_`. If you're just wondering what the transformers are doing to your data at each step, then you would have to take it out of the pipeline and do a `transform` on your data. The idea of a pipeline is that it does all of the work in a single step, without outputs.

Comment: If you want the outputs, you can use the solutions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743032/get-intermediate-data-state-in-scikit-learn-pipeline)